# Dealing with legacy database views in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, models, legacy-database

I am new to ruby and rails and I am having difficulty conceptualizing the MVC techniques in conjunction with database views.  I am dealing with a legacy database that has several viiews that are used to generate reports.

Where I get lost is how do I actually use a database view.  Should it be put in a model?  If so what exactly would that look like?

As an example the legacy db has a view called qryTranscriptByGroup.  It is used in the legacy application in an SQL statement such as "SELECT * FROM qryTranscriptByGroup WHERE group='test_group'". This returns a small number of records usually less than 100.

If i create a model, Transcript, how would I define a method like Transcript.find_by_group(group)?  As well, it would seem that I might need to prevent any other "find" methods as they would be invalid in this context.

There is also the the fact that the view is read-only and I would need to prevent any attempts to create, update or destroy it.

Perhaps I am going about this entirely the wrong way.  The bottom line is that I need to get information from several tables (models?) that represent the information about a user (a transcript). Actually one or more users (transcripts plural).

-Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a database view like a normal model.

In your case:

```
class Transcript < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "qryTranscriptByGroup"
  set_primary_key "if_not_id"
end
```

The query will be then:

```
Trascript.find_by_group('test_group')
```

without you need to declare anything.

Rails uses the method_missing method to magically generate find_by_column_name methods.

For the create/update/delete action you can simply delete them or not create them in the controller.

Comment: Amazing! This reminds me of switching to Mac - I kept trying to do things the "hard way" (aka MS Windows).  Once I started thinking of the "easiest way" to do things I had no further problems!

Comment: In the case of these transcripts, I really will be using them to create reports.  Is it safe to say that I do not need a Transcripts controller and transcript views.


IOW, I would grab a transcript and "analyze" it to present a report.  There would be different reports but they all use the same transcript for "analysis".

So, what I am ultimately going for is a a path like: /reports/summary/group1.  Is this a sensible approach?